# .htaccess file doesn't accept arabic

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule /(.*)\.html article.php?title=$1
```

to convert my url from `article.php?title=xxxx` to `article/xxxx.html`

url contains arabic and english...

so when i enter this url

```
article/تسريب-أولى-صور-هاتف-LG-G4s-الجديد.html
```

its working fine
but when i visit another article with the url

```
article/CloneApp-نقل-برامجك-المفضلة-بكامل-إعدادتها-من-ويندوز-إلى-اخر-نقرة-زر.html
```

not working: Objet non trouvé!

what is the problem (different between them?) why the first works and the second not!

thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Where does the "not working: Objet non trouvé!" error come from? Is that an Apache error? Make a screenshot. Error.log. Your RewriteRule doesn't handle either case, btw. `/(.*)` wouldn't match `/article/(.*)`.

Comment: Objet non trouvé!
L'URL demandée n'a pas pu être trouvée sur ce serveur. La référence sur la page citée semble être erronée ou perimée. Nous vous prions d'informer l'auteur de cette page de cette erreur.

Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le webmestre.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

Comment: Speak in english please, we cannot understand you.

Comment: i post everything with english .. only the title of the article because its the source of problem

Comment: What is the comment above then ? Objet non trouvé! L'URL demandée n'a pas pu être trouvée sur ce serveur. La référence sur la page citée semble être erronée ou perimée. Nous vous prions d'informer l'auteur de cette page de cette erreur. Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le webmestre.

Comment: it is the error that i get when opening the url up

Comment: yes but im beginner in htaccess ... i try it but i cant make it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most likely the issue is your rewriting rule. It explicitly is crafter
>   such that it only gets applied for requests that consist of only ascii
>   characters, an underscore or a hyphen in the slug part of the URL.
>   That obviously won't match arabic characters in the URL. So you have
>   to change your rule to accept more or less anything expect very
>   special characters:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id_art=$1 [NC,L]
```

Taken from this question asking a similar thing [How to enable arabic slug in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730798/how-to-enable-arabic-slug-in-htaccess)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, it works RewriteRule article/([^/]*)\.html article.php?title=$1