# How to rewrite arabic url in htaccess

Tags: php

How to rewrite arabic url in htaccess. I have create htaccess file it's working perfectly for english url but it is not working for arabic url. Acually i am developing project in two language english and arabic. For seo friendly url i am saving slug, It is running properly but in arabic it is not running

Comment: You will have to add details to your question to receive help or an answer: your current rules in your `.htaccess` file and some examples of URLs you want to rewrite. Note: please add those details to the question, there is an `edit` link for that. Do _not_ post additional details in comments. Thanks.

Comment: agree with @arkascha , and please include the order string you are using to call those pages . example : `www.yourwebsite.com/page.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 0):

u can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

and change the (page.php?id=$1) to feet your links

---

take a look on this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282546/7465452)

or this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29863433/7465452)

Comment: Where do you think this differs from the code the OP already uses?