# .htaccess not working with Arabic Letters

Tags: .htaccess

I know that there is a lot of questions like mine, and I hope that you do not down vote my question, because I have been struggling for almost a day without any solution, and hoping that someone here can help me.

I am developing a multilingual website, when the user enters an Arabic title, then automatically the urlkey will have Arabic letters.

My `.htaccess` file is rewriting all the English url's without any issue, but when there is Arabic letters, then the page is breaking and I am getting a `404 Not Found Page`

Find below my `.htaccess` file content, and I hope that you can help me

```
# -------------------------------------------
# | Safe URL                                |
# -------------------------------------------
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# -------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^home/([a-z]+)$                      index.php?lang=$1                                      [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^home                                   index.php                                               [L,NC]

{Tries Goes Here}
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$                              get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}           [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$                                              get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}                   [L,NC]

# -------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

As you can see in my `.htaccess` file, I have written the line `{Tries Goes Here}`, that is where I have tried the below lines, each at a time and did not worked

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$            get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&key3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([أ-يa-zA-Z0-9٠-٩_.-]+)$    get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&key3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9%-]+)$         get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&key3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}   [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9%-]+)$         get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&key3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}   [L,NE]
```

[Click Here](http://demo.worldarabeconomiclobby.com/get-page-contents.php?lang=en&key1=news&key2=world-arab-economic-lobby&key3=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86) for the working page, without URL Rewrite:

[Click Here](http://demo.worldarabeconomiclobby.com/en/news/world-arab-economic-lobby/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86) for the not working page, with URL Rewrite:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this answers [How to enable arabic slug in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730798/how-to-enable-arabic-slug-in-htaccess)

Try this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)$    get-page-contents.php?lang=$1&key1=$2&key2=$3&key3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]
```

Comment: Weird, I passed through this question, but never realized that he is using  `^/` in the last part of the URL. Anw thank you!